# Adjusting an image so that it fits a CD template outline

Tags: gimp, resize, perspective

I am trying to fit a picture of a CD into a CD label template. The issue is that the picture of the CD I took, despite best efforts, wasn't directly from 90 degrees above. So there's some perspective distortion. The xcf file is here for your reference: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z9XN6NeO8P0W2GYiNFb3mue-FD7Iw1gO/view?usp=sharing

As you can see, if I try to fit the outer outline of the disc to the template lines, then the center disc hole is out of place. And when I fit the center hole, then the outer outline of the disc is out of place. This is true for both horizontal and vertical axes. I have tried the in-built perspective tool - but despite extensive tinkering, it doesn't work.

I'd be really grateful if anyone can help me out with this! Regarding the xcf: the layer "IMG_3720.JPG" is the one I'm trying to fit. The rest of the layers are components of the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first fix the distortion that comes from the slightly sideways shot. This is done with the Perspective tool. You are lucky, you can use the grid on the CD to guide you (assuming it's a rectangular grid of course)

- First use the crop tool to crop the image layer to a rectangle that fits around the CD, no need to be too accurate. In the crop tool, don't forget the "Current layer only" and "Delete cropped pixels" options.
- Start the Perspective tool, the important options are `Corrective mode` and `Guides: number of lines`.

[image: Perspective options]

- Adjust the handles so that the tool's grid lines are parallel to the grid on the CD. Do your best but don't expect perfection, unless you had a perfect lens.

[image: Perspective operation]

- When you hit "Transform" Gimp will distort your layer so that the lines in the grid become rectangular. A side effect is that the CD center also becomes the geometric center. Note however that the CD will likely be slightly oblate. The perfect circle is for the next step.
- You can now adjust the size of the CD to fit your template. What I did was pull one of the templates later up above the image to use as a guide. If you do so make sure to re-select the CD layer otherwise you will edit that layer.
- Start the Scale tool, and make sure it is not in `Corrective` mode, and the the `Keep aspect ratio` is unchecked. You can also use `Composited preview` to better see how you CD image fits.
  [image: Scale options]
- Then scale your CD image vertically and horizontally to fit the image.
  [image: Scale operation]

For better results:

- If you still have the full size original CD image, you can apply the perspective correction on it independently.
- You then do the scaling to the template to fix both the size and the aspect ratio.

This method makes you work on more pixels for the perspective, and reduces the number of transformations (that always introduce a little bit of blur).

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the 3D Rotate tool for this.

1. Nudge the CD image so the the centre lines up with the middle of the template layer
2. Use the 3D rotate tool to try to get the outer edge of the CD to line up with the template.
3. Note that in the tool options for this tool, you can reduce the image opacity setting so you can see through the layers to match everything up.

An example achieved using this method (below). Note that this is not perfect but I think that's because the printing on the CD is not actually perfectly aligned to the centre.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Both your and xenoid's methods work perfectly for me. (accepted his/her answer though since that was posted earlier)